# Heap memory allocation crash with std::wstring

Tags: c++, unicode, crash, wstring

I have a big problem with std::wstring memory allocation. The program crash when I try to use this code:

```
size_t size;
mbstowcs_s(&size, NULL, 0, buffer, _TRUNCATE);
wchar_t *buffer2 = (wchar_t*)malloc(size + 1);
mbstowcs_s(&size, buffer, buffer_size, buffer, _TRUNCATE);
buffer2[size] = '\0';

std::wstring data(buffer);
```

the crash is on the last line and doesn't happen if I use the following line:

```
std::wstring data(L"hello");
```

the error is memory heap allocation failure and the result is the crash of the program. Why? What's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
wchar_t *buffer2 = (wchar_t*)malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`malloc` allocates a number of bytes - you wan't a number of `wchar_t`'s

If you're using c++, the correct way is:

```
wchar_t *buffer2 = new wchar_t[size+1];
```

Comment: @Stefano: No need, _TRUNCATE does that for you

Answer (score 5):

If you use std::wstring I assume you are using C++, dont use malloc, use new & delete (just a side note)

Answer (score 0):

std::vector seems to be a good way to make a buffer here. Its constructor receives elements number (not bytes) and you don't have to remember to delete the memory.